# SOAP Result returns negative number but does not recognize by IF ELSE

Tags: php, soap-client

I have here a SOAP Web Service request here that returns a negative value but when I used it on an IF ELSE method It does not recognize and the condition always go to ELSE even if the value is equal. Please see code below:

```
$url = 'http://0.0.0.0/webservice/SampleWebservice.asmx?WSDL';
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'ssl' => array(
'verify_peer' => false,
'verify_peer_name' => false,
'allow_self_signed' => true
)
));
$rq = ["Value1" => "value",
"ClientKey" => "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789"];
$service = new SoapClient($url, array('stream_context' => $context));
$xml = $service->GetWebServiceRequestVariable($rq);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);
$value = $array['GetWebServiceRequestVariable_Result']['any'];
//value returns -1
if($value == -1) {
 echo 'Value is negative';
}
else {
echo 'Value is positive';
}
//returns Value is Positive
```

Comment: Could you try to print out `$value` before the if statement, also check the data type using `var_dump($value);` Also, is it always going to have strictly `-1` or a value `> 0`,

Comment: it returns `<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><NewDataSet xmlns=""><Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><Value>-1</Value></Table></NewDataSet></diffgr:diffgram>`

Comment: is the above return value inside the variable `$value`?

Comment: the soap request returns -1 when it goes to IF ELSE, -1 is not recognize and always goes to else part.

Comment: i maybe missing something, but when i am trying to run part of your code using
`$array = json_decode(json_encode('<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><NewDataSet xmlns=""><Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0"><Value>-1</Value></Table></NewDataSet></diffgr:diffgram>'), true);`. i am getting `echo $array` as `-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I just convert the value to `SimpleXMLElement` then encode it to json using `json_encode` then decode it using `json_decode` then get the json element

```
$url = 'http://0.0.0.0/webservice/SampleWebservice.asmx?WSDL';
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'ssl' => array(
'verify_peer' => false,
'verify_peer_name' => false,
'allow_self_signed' => true
)
));

$rq = ["Value1" => "value",
"ClientKey" => "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789"];
$service = new SoapClient($url, array('stream_context' => $context));
$xml = $service->GetWebServiceRequestVariable($rq);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);

$xmljson = new SimpleXMLElement($array['GetWebServiceRequestVariable_Result']['any']);
$cvjson = json_encode($xmljson);
$bcjson = json_decode($cvjson,true);
$value = $bcjson["NewDataSet"]["Table"]["Value"];

if($value == -1) {
 echo 'Value is negative';
}
else {
echo 'Value is positive';
}
//now returns Value is negative
```